# 18.04 zfs+lxd causes container host to reboot under heavy load?

Tags: 18.04, crash, zfs, lxd

Spent a few days struggling with this and I guess 18.04 just aint ready for production.

18.04 server w/ lxd over zfs on raw block devices just reboots itself randomly.  No panic or output.  I have console=ttyS0 (over a null modem...etc ) kernel working with usual operation but absolutely no peep when it reboots.  No signs in ANY of the log files.

Hard to reproduce, but no-go for production. Happens when I try to run some of my 25Gb R+D scripts+programs+etc (now working as old 14.04 LXCs for years) that take hours to copy to each new lxd installation I have tried (tried generic "lxd init" too as well as "root zfs" and both "live-server" and plain "server" install ISOs).  The combination of a container madly running dns unbound to answer 100000s digs from another container while the third is doing heavy network I/O seems to cause the mysterious reboot - but not reliably.  Takes hours to reproduce but makes 18.04 not ready for my production environment. FBSD vimage jails on zfs ran fine for 7 years and old lxc on 14.04 non-zfs for 4 years running same setup (and freenas never a problem). Guess the linux zfs version isnt that stable yet for high load.  Tried root zfs with and w/o luks [1] and went down the rat hole of searching for under powered PSU (750W) and overheating (69C max w/ lm-sensors) options and all dead ends.  Tried on Phenom X6 and 4Ghz FX AMD processors with 32GB ECC-RAM (yes ecc - and bios setup that way). This seems like a genuine bug in the 18.04 lxd over multi-device zfs pool setup (yeah - I see the 120second lock msg for "sync" on console but I understand that is just a warning). My 2cents: my gut says this is a mem overwrite problem between network bridge (manually created br0. NO local bridge) and zfs fs. I took luks off so it aint cryptsetup. Giving up for now and go back to my own os work.  Maybe revisit in 6 mos.  Too bad.  lxd over zfs sounded like a good story and I would have loved to deploy.  I did learn a lot.

[1] https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Ubuntu-18.04-Root-on-ZFS

Conclusions after a few months.

I could not stop these random reboots from happening for 18.04+consumer mother boards (w/ECC + AMD) so I gave up and bought a used dell R610 (~$175 inc 48G ram 2xPSU) and the problem went away. But I thought I would share a few ratholes for you to avoid should you have the same issues.
1. dell likes raid.  So I had to replace the hard drive controlled w/ one flashed for "unraid zfs" (see ebay ~$50).  dont be afraid of breaking off some plastic tabs inside.
2. DO NOT USE the dell/broadcom on-board nics. They do not deal with ipv6 multicast in bridge mode (read: lost neighbor solicitations) well. 4-day rathole.
3. avoid messing with dell DRAC or universal configuration screens. Just try not to change anything that will force a reconfiguration or cause diminished performace.  Lost one dell to this.

Pros: redundant PSUs, good cooling, reasonable power usage (~100W w/ 6 2.5" drives)
Cons: slower cpu:  2x4-core 2.4Ghz intel versus 1x8-core 4.0Ghz AMD

Overall: I did not really gain much by going to 18.04. My 14.04 lxc setup had been up for years non stop w/ that same 4GHz AMD/mobo combo and had no IPv6 problems. I can only hope that I learned something useful for the month+ I spent upgrading to 18.04.

Comment: Plugged the same drives/setup into a Dell 1950 and havent seen the problem - other than a 2x increase in elec bill (0.32/kwh here) - so AMD FX w/ ecc still cheaper for me.  So maybe 18.04 doesnt like AMD chips? Maybe an ASLR or similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a known ZFS bug that has just been fixed and in the following days will get updated packages in Ubuntu,
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1781364
But for this bug you would get specific kernel messages on the console.

It is extremely rare not to get any relevant kernel messages on the serial console from a kernel crash. Unless it is a hardware issue related, for example, to overheating.

LXD runs in user-space. You would need to investigate Linux kernel subsystems.

Comment: Thank you so much. Good to know I can rule LXD out. As mentioned, I see the 120sec lockup message on the console often. Ruled out the overheat/psu problems in lab+rack setups. Dunno why I get nothing before reboot. I assume :
"cat /proc/sys/kernel/panic" 0 should "loop"/halt the kernel on panic but I still see nothing when the problem happens. I wonder if using ECC RAM (on my asus M5A78L-M/USB3) is interacting with the kernel in a bad way. But even a problem there I would expect would cause a message on the tty console. Thank you again for help. Its great to see zfs on linux!

Comment: The '120sec lockup kernel message is a generic message. You need to check with `dmesg` the details and whether the message is really about ZFS. I got such a message the other day it was about `cgroups`, not ZFS. I am trying to replicate the `cgroups` issue so that I can add `apport` info to the Launchpad report.

Comment: I suggest to join discuss.linuxcontainers.org for LXD discussions.